# How to make a call for tex2lyx

Tags: lyx, tex2lyx

I tried to use the LyX import `.tex` file tool from the File->Import->LaTeX(plain) menu but the `.lyx` file generated is unreadable because the imported file includes Hebrew letters.

So I think that I should better use the terminal and write-in the command

```
tex2lyx -e UTF8 source_file.tex output_file.lyx
```

But it seems that the software `tex2lyx` is not installed on my Mac OS, although I have LyX correctly installed.

So I tried to find a website from which I can download a `tex2lyx` installer, but I can't find any.

I am not a CLI nor a terminal expert so maybe I am missing something here.

Any help about that?

Comment: tex2lyx does come bundled with LyX, so it is somewhere on your computer. In fact, LyX calls tex2lyx "externally" (i.e., it runs a command just like we would on a terminal). Perhaps search for a file on your computer called "tex2lyx" and that will find it? I'm not sure why it's not in your path. On Ubuntu, I think (unless I modified something that I forgot about) it is in the PATH by default. A final note: LyX does not do a good job of importing non-simple .tex files because parsing LaTeX is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As scottkosty said in the comment, the reason for the error `command not found` when calling to `tex2lyx` right from the command prompt is because that this command is not in the shell path.

The app is actually located in `/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/` (on Mac OS), so you can simply do

```
>> /Applications/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/tex2lyx -e UTF8 source_file.tex output_file.lyx
```

and that does it.

Alternatively, add the app to the shell path in the `.zshrc` file (if you use [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell)):

```
PATH="/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/${PATH:+:${PATH}"; export PATH;
```

now you can make a call for it with the "implicit" path.